# Are there any personal blogs writing review of academic papers?

Tags: research-process

Are there any personal blogs writing articles on research papers?

Comment: Changed the question !!!

Comment: The answer to the question is "yes." Surely this isn't the whole question?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, lots!  For example, some of my personal favorites are [DrugMonkey](http://drugmonkey.scientopia.org/), [Neuroskeptic](http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/neuroskeptic/), and [In the Pipeline](http://pipeline.corante.com/).  Such blogs tend to have a lot of posts besides just paper analysis as well---general academia, war stories, the rest of life.

Comment: In the pipeline seems to be down at the moment. Did it close?